# How to update a nested data object in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection user_subscriptions like this:-

```
{
    user                        : '362382jwie92012kk209',
    plan                        : 'we2344r55jwie92vg56k209',
    planContemporayDetail       : {
                                    planName                : 'Test Name'
                                    planPrice               : 20,
                                    planStartAt             : 1729192839,
                                    planEndAt               : 1729232839,
                                    planExpire              : true,
                                    stripeSubscriptionId    : 'gwi289101023'
                                },
    status                      : 'active',
    canceledAt                  : null
}
```

I want to update `planContemporayDetail.planEndAt`, `planContemporayDetail.planExpire`, `status` and `canceledAt` based on the value of `user`, `plan`, `planContemporayDetail.stripeSubscriptionId`

Here is my nodeJS code:-

```
const userSubscriptionData  = {
                                '$set'        : { 
                                                  planContemporayDetail.planEndAt     : parseInt(parseInt(canceledAt) * 1000),
                                                  planContemporayDetail.planExpired   : true
                                                }, 
                                status        : canceledAt,
                                canceledAt    : parseInt(parseInt(canceledAt) * 1000)
                              };
const condition             = {
                                user      : userId, 
                                plan      : PlanId, 
                                planContemporayDetail.stripeSubscriptionId : stripeSubscriptionId
                              }
let subscriptionUpdate      = await UserSubscription.findOneAndUpdate(condition, userSubscriptionData);
```

But I am getting syntax error that `'invalid token at planContemporayDetail.planEndAt'`

How to fix this?

Comment: What is the value of `canceledAt`?

Comment: @ray 10 digit numeric value, ie. unix timestamp

Comment: I see 2 syntax errors: use quotation marks around a dotted field name, and all of the fields being modified should be inside the `$set` object.